# WPF printing on paper results in clipping

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am using the WPF PrintVisual method in order to print an object. Check my code below.

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = dialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(dialog.PrintTicket);
Double height = dialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
Double width = dialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
myObj.Measure(new Size(width, height));
myObj.Arrange(new Rect(new Point((capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth), (capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight)), new Size(width, height)));
dialog.PrintVisual(myObj, "Print in WPF with fit to printing page");
```

If I print this in xps, it works very well. But when I print on paper (A4 => 8.5 x 11 inches) then the object gets clipped from the right as it generates the margin at the left side of the paper. Can anyone tell me how I can avoid this margin on the paper and print the object full length?

Thanks

Comment: Based on the title I thought you were trying to print your documents on 'paper clips'.

Comment: What does this mean? : "But when I print on paper (A4 => 8.5 x 11 inches) ".

Answer (score 1):

It is very suspicious that you are using `dialog.PrintableAreaHeight` and `dialog.PrintableAreaWidth` for the printable size, but `capabilities.PageImageableArea` for the printable origin. These are unrelated measurements; try using

```
new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight)
```

in `myObj.Measure` and `myObj.Arrange`.